# the application openwnn (process jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn) has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am getting this  Exception " application openwnn (process jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn) has stopped in the emulator"

I am trying to develop a phone gap application in andriod platform , when i press the normal keyboard or Emulator keypad to type a letter in the html textbox i am  getting  this exception

Does any one know the reason for this exception and how to solve it?

I am using SDK version 10 (2.3)
Thanking you in Advance

Comment: Run "adb logcat" so you can see what errors are occurring. Generally a force close will have a stack trace that points to the offending line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings->Language and keyboard, and disable any Japanese input methods. Android (and the emulator's) default Japanese IME is based on OpenWNN, not sure why it's crashing with your PhoneGap app though.

Comment: I tried  disabling the Japanese IME input method , still it dint work . Then i tried a trick by typing on the andriod default browser , and the language was set to English .. Now the crashing problem is solved