# Error while Running Android Application on Emulator with IntelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: android, virtual

I am trying to run a Basic Android application using IntelliJ IDEA 11 IDE. I am running this under a Virtual Box which is running Ubuntu 12. 
The application code is something like this:
    package com.work;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

But when i run this application, i get the below error:

```
07-29 00:55:38.589: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-29 00:58:11.529: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-29 00:59:02.211: ERROR/BatteryService(68): usbOnlinePath not found
07-29 00:59:02.211: ERROR/BatteryService(68): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-29 00:59:02.262: ERROR/BatteryService(68): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-29 00:59:03.200: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(68): Couldn't open  
/sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-29 01:03:13.950: ERROR/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for   
/dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-29 01:03:13.950: ERROR/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for 
/dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-29 01:03:20.639: ERROR/System(68): Failure starting core service
    java.lang.SecurityException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
    at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
 07-29 01:04:02.261: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading   
/system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-29 01:04:02.801: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading     
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-29 01:04:03.243: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading     
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-29 01:04:03.490: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading     
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
 07-29 01:04:03.683: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading   
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-29 01:05:57.194: ERROR/ThrottleService(68): Could not open GPS configuration file    
/etc/gps.conf
07-29 01:06:09.580: ERROR/logwrapper(169): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such   
file or directory
07-29 01:06:09.890: ERROR/logwrapper(171): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such 
file or directory
07-29 01:06:10.551: ERROR/logwrapper(174): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such  
file or directory
07-29 01:06:17.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.settings
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS (has  
 extras) }
    Load: 5.09 / 3.45 / 1.74
    CPU usage from 16398ms to 2030ms ago:
    system_server: 46% = 26% user + 19% kernel / faults: 258 minor 2 major
    bootanimation: 28% = 25% user + 3% kernel
    adbd: 7% = 0% user + 7% kernel
    qemud: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    netd: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 21 minor
    logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 53% user + 43% kernel + 0% irq + 2% softirq
 07-29 01:06:29.433: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): Start proc com.android.launcher for   
 activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: pid=177 uid=10025 gids= 
 {}Load: 5.07 / 3.5 / 1.77
    CPU usage from 14712ms to 921ms ago:
    system_server: 59% = 37% user + 21% kernel / faults: 151 minor 1 major
    bootanimation: 36% = 32% user + 3% kernel
    adbd: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    qemud: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 99% = 68% user + 29% kernel + 0% irq + 0% softirq
  07-29 01:06:38.670: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.settings
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS (has   
  extras) }
    Load: 5.52 / 3.65 / 1.84
    CPU usage from 10310ms to 154ms ago:
    system_server: 52% = 34% user + 17% kernel / faults: 578 minor 1 major
    adbd: 4% = 0% user + 3% kernel
    logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 40 minor
    qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    init: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    -bootanimation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 62% user + 36% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
 07-29 01:08:10.033: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.mms
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED  
 cmp=com.android.mms/.transaction.MmsSystemEventReceiver }
    Load: 9.1 / 5.09 / 2.5
    CPU usage from 91361ms to 2237ms ago:
    system_server: 39% = 27% user + 11% kernel / faults: 5015 minor 3 major
    ndroid.launcher: 7% = 4% user + 3% kernel / faults: 5468 minor 4 major
    adbd: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    qemud: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    re-initialized>: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3064 minor
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 257 minor
    logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    installd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    vold: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    init: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    mediaserver: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 65% user + 33% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
 07-29 01:08:10.671: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): act=android.view.InputMethodLoad: 9.1 / 
 5.09 / 2.5
    CPU usage from 91630ms to 2506ms ago:
    system_server: 39% = 27% user + 11% kernel / faults: 5015 minor 3 major
    ndroid.launcher: 7% = 4% user + 3% kernel / faults: 5468 minor 4 major
    adbd: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    qemud: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    re-initialized>: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3064 minor
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 257 minor
    logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    installd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    vold: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    init: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    mediaserver: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 65% user + 33% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
  07-29 01:08:40.277: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
    Reason: Executing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP
    Load: 11.13 / 5.99 / 2.88
    CPU usage from 32462ms to 1576ms ago:
    system_server: 69% = 50% user + 18% kernel / faults: 1047 minor
    re-initialized>: 20% = 10% user + 9% kernel / faults: 3224 minor 4 major
    d.process.acore: 12% = 7% user + 5% kernel / faults: 3637 minor
    m.android.phone: 9% = 5% user + 3% kernel / faults: 3898 minor 9 major
    d.process.media: 5% = 3% user + 2% kernel / faults: 3170 minor
    adbd: 4% = 0% user + 4% kernel
    fsck_msdos: 4% = 2% user + 2% kernel / faults: 2161 minor 1 major
    roid.alarmclock: 3% = 1% user + 2% kernel / faults: 3118 minor
    qemud: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    logcat: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 35 minor
    re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 31 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    installd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +dexopt: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 62% user + 35% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
  07-29 01:10:17.328: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
    Reason: Executing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP
    Load: 10.77 / 7.32 / 3.74
    CPU usage from 126411ms to 5501ms ago:
    system_server: 31% = 18% user + 12% kernel / faults: 4061 minor
    re-initialized>: 10% = 6% user + 4% kernel / faults: 3695 minor
    adbd: 3% = 0% user + 3% kernel / faults: 12 minor
    qemud: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel / faults: 15 minor
    logcat: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 42 minor
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 295 minor
    kswapd0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 343 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 144 minor
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 171 minor
    re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 176 minor
    d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 94 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 59 minor
    installd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 17 minor
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    +ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +dexopt: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    -ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    -re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 64% user + 34% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
  07-29 01:10:49.375: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.launcher   
  (com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher)
    Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    Load: 11.35 / 7.68 / 3.94
    CPU usage from 29037ms to 7003ms ago:
    system_server: 58% = 33% user + 24% kernel / faults: 874 minor
    re-initialized>: 19% = 7% user + 12% kernel / faults: 2597 minor
    re-initialized>: 14% = 9% user + 5% kernel / faults: 154 minor
    adbd: 6% = 0% user + 5% kernel
    qemud: 3% = 0% user + 2% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    logcat: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    re-initialized>: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 29 minor
    d.process.acore: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
    roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 50% user + 47% kernel + 0% irq + 2% softirq
  07-29 01:10:56.577: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.launcher    
  (com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher)
    Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    Load: 11.35 / 7.68 / 3.94
    CPU usage from 29037ms to 7003ms ago:
    system_server: 58% = 33% user + 24% kernel / faults: 874 minor
    re-initialized>: 19% = 7% user + 12% kernel / faults: 2597 minor
    re-initialized>: 14% = 9% user + 5% kernel / faults: 154 minor
    adbd: 6% = 0% user + 5% kernel
    qemud: 3% = 0% user + 2% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    logcat: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    re-initialized>: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 29 minor
    d.process.acore: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
    roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 50% user + 47% kernel + 0% irq + 2% softirq
    Load: 11.88 / 7.99 / 4.1
    CPU usage from 20873ms to 4708ms ago:
    system_server: 55% = 28% user + 27% kernel / faults: 65 minor
    re-initialized>: 21% = 15% user + 5% kernel / faults: 141 minor
    re-initialized>: 8% = 2% user + 5% kernel / faults: 6 minor
    adbd: 7% = 0% user + 7% kernel
    qemud: 5% = 0% user + 5% kernel / faults: 7 minor
    logcat: 4% = 1% user + 2% kernel
    events/0: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    re-initialized>: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 12 minor
    d.process.acore: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
    roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 47% user + 49% kernel + 0% irq + 2% softirq
  07-29 01:11:36.900: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in com.android.settings
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS  
  cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider (has extras) }
    Load: 13.0 / 8.87 / 4.58
    CPU usage from 47124ms to 3282ms ago:
    system_server: 48% = 30% user + 18% kernel / faults: 1222 minor
    re-initialized>: 15% = 10% user + 4% kernel / faults: 1526 minor 3 major
    adbd: 4% = 0% user + 4% kernel
    qemud: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    logcat: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 75 minor
    d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    +ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 54% user + 43% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
   07-29 01:12:07.043: ERROR/ActivityManager(68): ANR in jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
    Reason: Executing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP
    Load: 13.34 / 9.21 / 4.79
    CPU usage from 32868ms to 10154ms ago:
    ronsoft.openwnn: 48% = 31% user + 17% kernel / faults: 4021 minor 1 major
    system_server: 39% = 23% user + 15% kernel / faults: 166 minor 1 major
    re-initialized>: 19% = 16% user + 2% kernel / faults: 105 minor
    adbd: 4% = 0% user + 4% kernel
    qemud: 3% = 0% user + 2% kernel
    roid.alarmclock: 3% = 1% user + 1% kernel / faults: 199 minor
    logcat: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel
    re-initialized>: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
    d.process.acore: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    fsck_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
    d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    +ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    TOTAL: 100% = 59% user + 37% kernel + 0% irq + 2% softirq
```

Can anyone help me with the Solution if possible. I am not able to figure out anything from the error. The above are the logs from the filter only as error. I can get the verbose logs also if required. Let me know in case something has been missed.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Am I getting this right: You are trying to run an Android emulator on Ubuntu which is running inside a Virtualbox VM?

Comment: Yes Correct. Is something Wrong ?

Comment: It might be that the Android emulator tries to do low-level operations which Virtualbox doesn't support.

Comment: Is there any way out of this ? And you are saying that the same error won't come if I run it on real system rather than Virtual one ?

Comment: What is this `jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn.OpenWnnJAJP`? If I google it, here is the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9900409/413127 Disable the Japanese Keybaord in the emulator :-/

Comment: That is what I am also trying to figure out. I tried to find the solution at other places but it didn't help. The error is totally over the head.

Comment: Well I can tell you the error isn't intellij. It's something to do with your emulator running on ubuntu. Delete it and create a new 1?